# Retrieving the first item from the list and converting it in int

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following class as shown below

```
public class BrokerInvoiceLineItem {


    private int attachmentCount;

public int getAttachmentCount() {
        return attachmentCount;
    }

    public void setAttachmentCount(int attachmentCount) {
        this.attachmentCount = attachmentCount;
    }
}
```

the named query in xml is

```
<sql-query name="attachmentQuery">
     <![CDATA[select count(iilnmp.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID) from IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP iilnmp , 
                                                IOA_INVOICE_LINE_NOTES iiln , IOA_INVOICE_LINE iil
                                               where   iilnmp.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID = iiln.ID and iiln.INLI_ID =iil.id and iil.ID = ?]]>
</sql-query>
```

now below is the operation that i am doing where from a list at index 0 i am retrieving the value but i am getting an compilation error as i need to cast the value stored at index 0 into int type then only i will be able to set
please advise how can i achieve the same

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("attachmentQuery");
                query.setParameter(0, itrBrokerInvoiceLineItem.getId());
                List attachCount = query.list();
                if (attachCount != null && attachCount.size() > 0) {
                    if (attachCount.get(0) != null) {
                        itrBrokerInvoiceLineItem.setAttachmentCount(attachCount.get(0));
                    }
                }
```

the compilation error that i am getting is `The method setAttachmentCount(int) in the type BrokerInvoiceLineItem is not applicable for the arguments (Object)`

I have edited my question please as i am using hibernate 3.1 in which  query.getsingleresult method is not there please advise

Comment: Where exactly is the error? what is the stack trace?

Comment: How does the named query look like?

Comment: You have created a `List` in raw type (type `Object`) and you try to store a value from it in `int` type. That is not allowed. I don't know what values the `Query.list()` returns but try to declare your list using the diamond operators (`List<Integer>`).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
List attachCount = query.list();
```

With this

```
List<Integer> attachCount = (List<Integer>) query.list();
```

Comment: You can't use a base type in diamond operators. Instead, use the `Integer` type.

Comment: ya that was the mistake

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question you want 1st result after executing your query.
So, i will prefer you to use `query.getSingleResult()` with handling exception rather than `query.list()`. Which will return `Object`.

---

(After Edit)
it seems that you want count based on some parameters.
So i will prefer you to change in name query with this

```
<sql-query name="attachmentQuery">
     <![CDATA[select * from IOA_INV_LINE_NOTE_MAP iilnmp , 
                                                IOA_INVOICE_LINE_NOTES iiln , IOA_INVOICE_LINE iil
                                               where   iilnmp.INV_LINE_NOTE_ID = iiln.ID and iiln.INLI_ID =iil.id and iil.ID = ?]]>
</sql-query>
```

And then use `query.list().getSize()` which will return `int`